# Why would a CSV attachment appear as text in the body?

Tags: email, csv, attachment, mime-types

I've just implemented some code that emails a bunch of our clients with a CSV file attachment.

Some (not many) have got back to us complaining that they don't get an attachment at all - just the CSV text inside the body of the email. Most however are fine.

I suspect that it's different mail clients that are treating the attachment differently but I don't have enough info yet to be sure.

I'm using .NET's MailMessage class with the Attachment.CreateAttachmentFromString() method. The MIME type I'm specifying for the attachment is text/csv.

Anyone have any idea what the heck is going on?

Ta muchly

David

Comment: This used to happen to me a lot back in the bad old days of UUencoding, MIME types and Eudora & Pegasus and their brethren. Seriously though I haven't had to even think about these things in well over 10 years..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another possibility is that the failing email clients do not recognize the MIME type 'text/csv' and thus are showing the content uninterpretted in-line -- it may actually go through better as 'text/plain'.

---

*Edit:* I just sent a test message with a CSV attachment from Outlook to my Gmail, and used the menu option "Show original" to see the actual multi-part content, and this is what I see:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="test.csv"
Content-Description: test.csv
Content-Disposition: attachment;
  filename="test.csv";
  size=44;
  creation-date="Wed, 28 Apr 2010 14:13:20 GMT";
  modification-date="Wed, 28 Apr 2010 14:13:43 GMT"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

So it looks like **'application/octet-stream'** will do the trick.

Comment: Interestingly, I was able to email one of the guys with a CSV file I had attached using Outlook. He said it appeared as an attachment. So maybe if I find out the MIME type that Outlook used for the attachment, that might fix the problem?

Comment: (Comment formatting was screwy, so I added my results to the answer above.)

Comment: Yes, my own tests confirm this. To get a CSV file attachment to work correctly in some email clients, you have to tell them it's a binary file! Work that one out...

Answer (score 0):

You are probably on the right track.  I would start by asking those who have the issue exactly what client and version they are using, have them forward you the message that they received.  And if you find that those messages can be opened correctly from your client, offer a list of acceptable clients they can forward to as a temporary work around.

After that, it's all digging into docs, and figuring out how to make it work.

Good luck.

### EDIT

It would probably also be a good idea to find out if they are opening their email plain text, or html, and if their company has any policies about attachments that may be configured into their clients.